# How to install Hyper-V on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v, haxm

For installing HAXM (to use Android Studio), I need Hyper-V.

Normally I shall restart the Hyper-V option in Control Panel - Windows feature on/off, however I don´t have any Hyper-V option, apparently cause I have Windows 7 Home Premium. (I have already enabled "Visualization" in my BIOS). But I cannot find any solution on how to install Hyper-V. Could you please advise me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V was never part of Windows 7. It was part of Server 2008 R2 and [Microsoft added it first to the client Windows versions in Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/07/bringing-hyper-v-to-windows-8.aspx). Here you need the Pro or Enterprise Edition.